# Recursion in JAX

Tags: python, recursion, jax

I'm trying to write a (matrix) exponentiate-by-squaring algorithm in JAX. Unfortunately, I don't understand traced variables very well, which is complicating matters.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.lax as jlax

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def matpow(A, n):
    dim = A.shape[0]
    return jlax.switch(
        n,
        [lambda: jnp.identity(dim),
         lambda: A,
         lambda: jlax.cond(
             jnp.floor_divide(n, 2) == jnp.true_divide(n, 2),
             lambda: matpow(jnp.dot(A, A), jnp.floor_divide(n, 2)),
             lambda: jnp.dot(A, matpow(jnp.dot(A, A), jnp.floor_divide(n, 2)))
         )])
```

However, attempting to run this with, say, `matpow(2 * jnp.eye(4), 5)` throws an error midway through compilation:

```
ValueError: Non-hashable static arguments are not supported, as this can lead to unexpected cache-misses. Static argument (index 1) of type <class 'jax.interpreters.partial_eval.DynamicJaxprTracer'> for function matpow is non-hashable.
```

... I have no idea what that means, to be quite honest, but it's doubly confusing because as far as I can tell `n` should just be an integer and therefore has a trivial hash.

Other attempts have included: using `jnp.binary_repr` (not yet implemented), using `np.binary_repr` (TracerIntegerConversionError, even though `n` is marked static), and a 'wrapped' version of the above recursive function in which I defined a separate function `recpow` internally to `matpow` (hit the recursion limit.)

What do I need to do to make this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this kind of approach—trace-time recursion with the stopping condition depending on a traced value—is not possible in JAX, because when the code is traced, the value of `n` is unknown and so there's no way for the function tracing to terminate.

You can fix this by keeping your recursion condition static, which requires not using constructs like `lax.switch`. Here's an example roughly equivalent to your function:

```py
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def matpow(A, n):
  dim = A.shape[0]
  n = int(n)
  if n < 0:
    raise ValueError("n < 0 not implemented")
  elif n == 0:
    return jnp.identity(dim)
  elif n == 1:
    return A
  elif n // 2 == n / 2:
    return matpow(A @ A, n // 2)
  else:
    return A @ matpow(A @ A, n // 2)
```

If you need `n` to be dynamic, another option is to express your logic in terms of [`jax.lax.while_loop`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.while_loop.html), which is capable of breaking the loop based on a traced value. An example of a loop-based approach for matrix power can be found in JAX's implementation of `jax.numpy.linalg.matrix_power`: https://github.com/google/jax/blob/a2a84c40d526855dff158b51f5aceccbca9c953e/jax/_src/numpy/linalg.py#L72-L107

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I eventually figured out that there was some sort of type-inference problem with using `jnp.floor_divide` and `true divide`; switching to python `//` and `/` fixed that but gave me the recursion bug you mentioned. `while_loop` seems to work though!